# Is a norm in $\mathbb{R}^d$ increasing in every coordinate?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Consider any norm $\|\cdot\|$ in the $d$ dimensional Euclidean space and consider a fix point there $x$ such that all of its coordinates are positive. Let $e_k$ some vector in the standard basis of this space and consider the function $t \mapsto \|x +te_k\|$ for non negative $t$. Is this function increasing?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the answers (I can see there are some answers but my app is failing I guess). I corrected my question, officially started was way too false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hopeless: Draw in $\mathbb{R}^2$ a parallelogram symmetric with respect to the origin, where the upper side is slanted going up to the right, like in the following figure:

[image: ball with upper side slanted going up to the right]

Since this is a convex set and symmetric with respect to the origin, its interior is the unit ball of a norm of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now pick a point on the upper side and you'll see that if you move it to the right, it will *enter* the ball, hence its norm will *decrease*.

That was for the intuitive and visual part.

---

For the formal part:

Define the norm
$$\forall u=(u_x,u_y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,\ N(u)=\frac14\lvert u_x+u_y\rvert+\frac12\lvert u_x-u_y\rvert.$$
It is straightforward to check that $N$ is a norm (and is in fact obtained from the $1$-norm and a linear bijection). The ball is shown on the figure above.

Let $u=(1,5/3)$. Clearly $N(u)=1$. Now for $t=1/3$,
$u+e_x/3=(4/3,5/3)$ and $N(u+e_x/3)=11/12<1=N(u)$.

---

Answer (score 5):

It is not too hard to check that $\|(x,y)\|^2 = 4 (x-y)^2 + (x+y)^2$ defines a
norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. (The level sets an ellipse rotated by 45°.)

Let $\phi(t) = \|(t,1)\|^2$ and note that $\phi'(0) = -6$.

If you draw a little picture it will be visually obvious what is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\|\cdot\|:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R, (x_1,x_2)\mapsto |x_1-x_2|+ |x_1|$. This is a norm:

$\|\cdot\|\geq 0$ is obvious. If $\|x\| = 0$ then $|x_1| = 0$ and $x_1 = x_2$, hence $x_2=0$ aswell.

$\|\lambda x\| = |\lambda|\|x\|$ is obvous.

$\begin{align*}\|x+y\| &= |x_1-x_2+y_1-y_2|+|x_1+y_1| \leq |x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|+|x_1|+|y_1|\\
&= \|x_1\|+\|x_2\|.\end{align*}$

But now consider $x=(1,\frac 12)$. We have $\|x\| = \frac 32$ but $\|x+\frac 12e_2\| = \|(1,1)\| = 1 < \frac 32 = \|x\|$.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample for that function being strictly increasing is $\|.\|_{max}:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\|x\|_{max}=\max_i|x_i|$ where $x_i$ are the components of $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Take $x=2e_1+\sum_{i=2}^de_i$. Then $t\mapsto \|x+te_2\|_{max}$ is constant for $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: The coordinates of $x$ are not all positive though, but $x=e_1+1/2e_2$ works as well on $[0,1/2]$.

Comment: Right. I'll edit to correct it. Thanks!

Comment: I took the definition of "increasing" as "not true it decreases strictly in some open interval"