# Any norm on $\mathbb R^n$ induces product metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be metric spaces and $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb R^n$. Then it's easily seen that if $\|\cdot\|$ is monotonic in each coordinate while (others fixed) in the orthant $[0, +\infty)^n$, then $d(x, y) := \bigl\| \bigl( d_1(x_1, y_1), \ldots, d_n(x_n, y_n) \bigr) \bigr\|$ defines a metric on $X_1\times\cdots\times X_n$. Monotonicity gives an easy assurance that triangle equality is satisfied.

Now, as [this SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2066252/673223) shows, there do exist norms on $\mathbb R^n$ which don't fit the monotonicity requirement.

**Question:** Does $d$ due to such norms still form a metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example, let $X_1 = X_2$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the usual $\infty$-norm, $\|\cdot\|$ be the $1$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ *with respect to the basis* $\{(0, \frac{1}{2}), (1, 1)\}$. Let $x = ((0, 0), (0, 0)), y = ((1, 0), (0, 0)), z = ((0, 1), (1, 0))$, then $d(x, y) = \|(1, 0)\| = \|(1, 1) - 2(0, \frac{1}{2})\| = 3$, $d(x, z) = \|(1, 1)\| = 1$, and $d(z, y) = \|(1, 1)\| = 1$. Hence, we do not have $d(x, y) \leq d(x, z) + d(z, y)$ and $d$ is not a metric.